Verify the result of a determinant (solved)
I need help with a problem where I am asked to verify this determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ -b & a & d & -c  \\ -c & -d & a & b \\ -d & c & -b & a\end{vmatrix} = (a² + b² + c² + d²)²$$
I have been trying to perform elementary operations on rows or columns on the determinant, however, I am not achieving the expected result.
EDIT: After reviewing the shape of the matrix I find that it is similar to an orthogonal matrix although without being one, so:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c & d \\ -b & a & d & -c  \\ -c & -d & a & b \\ -d & c & -b & a\end{pmatrix}_4$$
$$AA^t = \begin {pmatrix} x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x\end{pmatrix}_4; x = a²+b²+c²+d²$$
$$det(AA^t) = x⁴ \rightarrow det(A)det(A^t)=x⁴ \rightarrow det(A)² = x⁴$$
$$det(A) = x² \rightarrow det(A) = (a²+b²+c²+d²)²$$

Yes, thanks, I already fixed it
